# Cannot run XAMPP MySQL module with a MySQL server already installed?

Tags: mysql, windows, apache, xampp, ports

I need to use both the XAMPP MySQL module and a seperate MySQL server for personal reasons. I run Windows 7 64-bit and I use MySQL 5.7.16 and XAMPP v5.6.24.

I have tried changing the port that the XAMPP MySQL module uses in the XAMPP control panel configurations, in the my.ini file, in the php.ini file, and in the config.inc.php file. When I click "Start" for the MySQL module in the XAMPP control panel, I get a message that says "[mysql] Attempting to start MySQL service..." but it never gets beyond that. It doesn't even give me an error message.

For now, I have to [uninstall the MySQL server and wipe it completely from my computer](http://www.windowsvalley.com/uninstall-mysql-from-windows/) every time I want to use the XAMPP module. This is proving to be a pretty daunting task, though. Any suggestions would be appreciated.